# matrices problems, unclear concept need explanation.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$I.A
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$II.A
        \begin{pmatrix}
        y_1 \\
        y_2 \\
        y_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$III.A
        \begin{pmatrix}
        z_1 \\
        z_2 \\
        z_3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        1 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

a)Is it possible for each of these systems to have infinitely many solutions?

b)Is it possible for system III to have no solutions, while each of the other two systems has infinitely many solutions?

So I know the answer is No and Yes. However I have no idea how to approach part a) while for part b it seems I only need to have a zero vector would do the thing.

Hopefully someone can be generous to guide me through this problem.

Comment: Any restrictions on the column vectors (other than they're obviously not $0$)?

Comment: If a system has solutions is because the vector on the right hand side is in the span of the columns of the matrix. The three vectors on the right of the three systems span $\mathbb{R}^3$. So, $A$ has rank $3$, because its columns span three vectors that generate $\mathbb{R}^3$. Therefore it is invertible. So, each system has exactly one solution.

Comment: You can get case (b) just by letting $A$ be a matrix with columns being the vectors on the right of the first two systems, and the extra column equal to zero.

Comment: The main idea we used above, which is also very useful in linear algebra in many other problems, is that $Ax$ is just a linear combination of the columns of $A$.

Comment: so I understand A now, could you explain a bit more on b it seems a bit confusing....

Comment: (b) Take $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: so because this system consists of the right hand side of the system, then y and z or x and z can produce infinite number of combinations(solutions to the system) while the third system could not because they can never produce 1 for the last row. Is this an acceptable reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

ABC comment is the best because it is conceptual, but here is an algebraic approach for part (a) :

$$U = Y - X$$
$$V = Z - Y$$

$$A \begin {bmatrix} x_1 & u_1 & v_1 \\
                     x_2 & u_2 & v_2 \\
                     x_3 & u_3 & v_3 
  \end {bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since a matrix can only have 1 inverse if any, if the 3 equations have any solution at all, then they have only 1, which is 
$$\begin {bmatrix} x_1 & u_1 & v_1 \\
                   x_2 & u_2 & v_2 \\
                   x_3 & u_3 & v_3 
  \end {bmatrix} = A^{-1}$$